# Changing virtual memory using batch

Tags: windows, memory, batch, batch-file, virtual-memory

I am making a program using batch to boost pc performance and I have now come to the stage where I need to edit [windows virtual memory](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/change-virtual-memory-size#1TC=windows-7) to a size that I can change in the code. if needed it can be done in a .reg as I can make the batch file execute it. can any one help. My os is windows 7 ultimate 32bit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how I do mine, much easier to edit than a .reg file as the registry stores this field as a hex blob.  Also included a dual page file scenario, if need be delete `, d:\pagefile.sys 4096 4096` for a single c:\ pagefile.

```
start /wait /b powershell -command "Set-ItemProperty -Path 'registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management' -Name 'PagingFiles' -Value 'c:\pagefile.sys 1024 1024, d:\pagefile.sys 4096 4096'"
#
```

Here is registry version of same settings, but as you can see it cannot be edited directly.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management]
"PagingFiles"=hex(7):63,00,3a,00,5c,00,70,00,61,00,67,00,65,00,66,00,69,00,6c,\
  00,65,00,2e,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,20,00,31,00,30,00,32,00,34,00,20,00,31,00,\
  30,00,32,00,34,00,2c,00,20,00,64,00,3a,00,5c,00,70,00,61,00,67,00,65,00,66,\
  00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,2e,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,20,00,34,00,30,00,39,00,36,00,\
  20,00,34,00,30,00,39,00,36,00,00,00,00,00
```

For a true batch method, reg.exe might be an alternative to the powershell snip.  But the syntax is straight up binary.  See JRV's final post in this thread

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/03ba4174-78ee-45ee-aa26-d8a0eb610f85/add-reg-key-to-registry-with-hex-data

This would need be re-written with the exact hex of whatever settings you make.

```
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Toolbar\ShellBrowser" /v "{83E8BF99-F3C0-4475-B453-9F9E8E4548C3}" /t REG_BINARY /d 09bfe883c0f37544b4539f
```

Comment: I encapsulated the powershell command so that it works from a .cmd or .bat file, in case that isn't clear.